# Is there an easy way to "mount" k8s config map entries on a client machine?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I am debugging an app running in a k8s pod using telepresence. That app mounts several different config maps and I have to mimic it on my client machine, which is annoying, because these config maps may change from time to time.

Is there a way to "mount" these config maps on my client machine? I could probably write a script that does it, but I do not want to invent a wheel.

Comment: Can't you use `$kubectl cp` to copy the replica of configmap to client machine?

Comment: Use or write a small Cloudwatch tool, to observe config maps and secrets. There are a lot of libs which can do this. You can then automatically write them to your local environment.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend checking out mirrord:

https://mirrord.dev

It makes a local process mimic a running pod, including environment variables, so should cover your config map use case. It also proxies incoming and outgoing traffic and file access, but this can be disabled via configuration if not required.

Answer (score 0):

I think Intercept Specifications may be what you're after.  They recently released this:

https://www.getambassador.io/docs/telepresence/latest/reference/intercepts/specs

Comment: But the intercept spec does not allow to mount a config map. Could you elaborate on how it would help with my question?